# Couldn't get any new function for "module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'assign_weights_to_keras_model'"

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Can anybody help me to replace this function? I am getting error for these code:

```
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(eval_model, state.model)
```

Answer (score 0):

The

> tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model

function has been removed from the new version of TensorFlow Federated.

The solution depends on which TFF version you are using.
One replacement is:

Try replacing

```
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(eval_model, state.model)
```

with

```
state.model.assign_weights_to(eval_model)
```

2nd replacement is(latest version):

Try replacing

```
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(eval_model, state.model)
```

with

```
tff.learning.models.ModelWeights.assign_weights_to(
```

Comment: Share your code sample, so that can give you more hints.